# What happen after new plugin get installed in term of permissions?

Tags: installation, linux

Using Ubuntu to host WordPress, I am wondering about permissions of files for newly installed plugin, how would they be executable?

permissions for the folder that has the wordpress installation:

```
drwxrwsr--  7 ubuntu deploy  4096 Oct 17 17:56 blog
```

Should I configure blog directory so that new files inherit blog directory permissions too? or this is already taken care of by WordPress? ex: it will run command chmod 775 at the newly installed plugin folder??

Any enlightenment is appreciated? I really like to understand.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I'm not seeing a specific question that can be concretely answered, just general confusion. Have you tried installing a plugin and looking at the file permissions? Is there a problem you're trying to solve?